# How to mask numpy structured array on multiple columns?

Tags: python, numpy, mask, masked-array

I have a numpy structured array with a dtype such as:

```
A = numpy.empty(10, dtype=([('segment', '<i8'), ('material', '<i8'), ('rxN', '<i8')]))
```

I know I can create a mask such as:

```
A[A['segment'] == 42] = ...
```

Is there a way to create a mask on multiple columns? For example (I know this doesn't work, but I wish it did):

```
A[A['segment'] == 42 and A['material'] == 5] = ...
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `&` operator instead of `and`:

```
A[(A['segment'] == 42) & (A['material'] == 5)]
```

Note that extra parantheses are required.